# Should this question be reopened or a new and improved version of the question posted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

The question [Do stars come on like LEDs or wick lamps?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/31838/7982) was closed as duplicate of [Timescale of ignition of a protostar?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/764/7982).

A comment [says](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/31838/do-stars-come-on-like-leds-or-wick-lamps#comment58066_31838)

> Actually, it's not the same question, because this question is about how the star "turns on" like a light, and exhibits confusion between that and the onset of fusion-- which is completely different. Fusion onset does not change the luminosity of a star, it merely allows the star to achieve equilibrium and a more gradual evolution rate. So this should be emphasized in the answer to this question-- regardless of the timescale for fusion to begin, the star is already bright.

There is now a vote to reopen and I'd thought about clicking "edit and reopen" but the question is by an unregistered user who has not been active since the moment the question was posted on May 12 2019.

In this particular case is it better to make a substantial edit and vote to reopen with the risk that a good answer will never be accepted, or to instead for someone (ideally the first reopen voter) to post a new question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case since it is a year old and the user appears to be no longer with us, I would advise strongly against making substantial edits to the question. If you would like to reopen, please cast your vote based upon the current form of the question.

Comment: This makes the most sense, thanks!